# Disable Foreign Key Constraints Mysqlalchemy ORM (Python)

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, orm

I have two models with a relationship between them something like this:

```
Base = declarative_base()
class Model1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'm1'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, unique=True)
    Name = Column(String(255))
    info = Column(String(255))
    
    m2s = relationship("Model2", back_populates="m1")

class Model2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'm2'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, unique=True)
    Name = Column(String(255))
    info = Column(String(255))
    m1 = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('m1.id'))
```

Now the issue arises when I try to insert a record into **Model2** which doesn't have a corresponding Foreign Key in **Model1**. The error I get is something like this:

```
(pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails'
```

Tried looking for many solutions, but none helped. I'm sure there must be a way to insert data in **Model2** without having to bother about its Foreign Key constraint.

Comment: This code won't run: (1) no length defined for string columns (2) "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Comment: updated the question with string lengths

Comment: The foreign key in m2 must be an integer, because m1.id is an integer.  Review [this doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many) for how to set up the relationship correctly.  Once these issues are fixed, an M2 can be inserted without error.  If you still can't get it working, share a [mre] that reproduces the actual error that you are seeing.

Comment: Even after changing that to Integer, if I insert something in Model2 with no respective m1 as foreign key, it won't insert it but give the same error as stated above.